# cant login into heroku with ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

**update** It started working by itself after I restarted windows

I recently installed ruby 2.0 and heroku, but everytime I try to login into heroku, i get the following error

```
C:\kick\app\app>heroku login
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such f
ile -- readline (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/heroku-2.35.0/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Then add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rb-readline'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Heroku gem? If so, please use the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com)

Comment: i've got both installed, it worked fine after i restarted my machine

Comment: Both? Which one is your machine using? The gem is deprecated.

Comment: i installed the toolbelt first and then did gem install heroku.. something wrong?

Comment: So it's likely using the gem and not the Toolbelt. You should be using the Toolbelt: `gem uninstall heroku` that guy